# Name of anime I only saw 1 episode of that took place in the desert

Tags: story-identification, anime, episode-identification

Here is what I remember of it and other details:

1. I watched it around 2012-13.
2. I am pretty sure it was an anime.
3. Had the stereotypical anime tropes(chibi, people getting comically hit into yesteryear, etc.)
4. Was a tv show and not a film.
5. Took place in a desert, probably near a canyon, at least that episode did.
6. I think they were there to visit a relative, but they may have lived there, I doubt it though.
7. MCs consisted of a teen boy and girl, pretty sure they were brother and sister. I vaguely remember a toy/plushie being part of the cast.
8. Nothing too crazy or magical if I recall correctly, but I think they jump a chasm in their car. That being said, I am pretty sure it was in the fantasy genre, though it might have been either sci-fi or action.

I think it might have been *Bleach*, but I looked up *Bleach* and desert and found nothing that I recall from that episode.

Comment: They don't allow Story ID period, but we don't allow Story ID that's not about scifi or fantasy. There needs to be *something* that makes it on-topic here.

Comment: @Valorum if the OP thinks the story they’re looking for is SFF-nail we usually give the benefit of the doubt in case it is so in light of the edit I think we can do that here.